# Arangodb stops async replication after some time

Tags: kubernetes, replication, arangodb

I use ArangoDB 3.2.2 on Kubernetes. I have one master db and one slave db. on the slave db inside the arangosh I enter the following commands:

```js
db._useDatabase("mydb");

equire("@arangodb/replication").setupReplication({
  endpoint: "tcp://master:8529",
  username: "root",
  password: "123456",
  database: "mydb",
  verbose: true,
  includeSystem: false,
  incremental: true,
  autoResync: true,
  maxConnectRetries: 20,
  adaptivePolling: false,
  idleMinWaitTime: 0.001,
  idleMaxWaitTime: 1.5,
  chunkSize: 5000
});
```

The command blocks for a few seconds and then the replication is started and I can see that the collections from the master db are replicated to the slave. However, after some time the replication stops.

When I run:
require("@arangodb/replication").applier.state
This is what I see:

```
{ 
  "state" : { 
    "running" : true, 
    "lastAppliedContinuousTick" : "6384020", 
    "lastProcessedContinuousTick" : "6384026", 
    "lastAvailableContinuousTick" : "6389353", 
    "safeResumeTick" : "6382367", 
    "progress" : { 
      "time" : "2017-11-15T12:14:09Z", 
      "message" : "fetching master log from tick 6382367, first regular tick 6367894, barrier: 0, open transactions: 0", 
      "failedConnects" : 0 
    }, 
    "totalRequests" : 1155, 
    "totalFailedConnects" : 0, 
    "totalEvents" : 83, 
    "totalOperationsExcluded" : 0, 
    "lastError" : { 
      "errorNum" : 0 
    }, 
    "time" : "2017-11-15T12:15:47Z" 
  }, 
  "server" : { 
    "version" : "3.2.2", 
    "serverId" : "77969163868004" 
  }, 
  "endpoint" : "tcp://master:8529", 
  "database" : "mydb" 
}
```

When I run the replication command again I see that the collections are being replicated again...

How can I initialize a stable replication process?
I understand that this is an asynchronous replication but in my use case I need the slave to be updated as fast as possible... Does my replication config is fit to my needs?

Comment: If I understand correctly, the replication applier reports its state as "running" while other analysis shows that is effectively not applying any changes from the master? I would like to understand how you can to the conclusion that the applier does not work. Are you looking at the document counts in collections? Or are you looking at multiple progress results of the applier's `state()` command? At least here the tick values and the `totalRequests` value should increase over time. If they do not, then the applier seems to be hanging indeed.

Comment: By the way, the configured `chunkSize` value seems rather low. It's just 5KB which may mean batches returned by the master will be at most that big. 5KB is not much if many documents get inserted/modified/removed or if document size is typically bigger than around 100 bytes.
I suggest increasing the `chunkSize` value to around 1 MB and see if it helps, or even use the default value.
I would also suggest to turn on `adaptivePolling`, because it will mean fewer HTTP requests are being made from slave to master when there is not much to do.

Comment: Did the replication log any errors to the ArangoDB logfile about some data it could not apply?

Comment: This is the slave log:
2017-11-16T07:52:53Z [7] INFO {replication} fetching master log from tick 6607800, first regular tick 6544726, barrier: 0, open transactions: 3
2017-11-16T07:52:54Z [7] INFO {replication} fetching master log from tick 6607800, first regular tick 6544726, barrier: 0, open transactions: 3

It is on the same tick... But the collection doc count doesn't change and it is not replicating the last collection I created on the master.  I also increased the chunk size to 5MB but it didn't change the behavior.
By the way my db consists of a lot of collections, is it a problem?

Comment: When I start to populate the collection in the master is see this log entry:
2017-11-16T09:08:38Z [7] INFO {replication} fetching master log from tick 8228672, first regular tick 8182026, barrier: 0, open transactions: 0

and it stucks.. (before it there was a log entry every second or so...)
eventually after some time this appears in the log:
2017-11-16T09:23:39Z [7] WARNING {queries} timed out after 900 s waiting for exclusive-lock on collection 'my_col'

Comment: Are there any other processes (apart from arangod itself) that attempt to write data on the slave, specifically into collection `my_col`?

Comment: The processes that are using the slaves are only reading data...
But I noticed that when I import collections via the Arango's UI it is synced without any issues.. When I ingest data via my application the replication starts to break.. Could it be that I abuse the master some how and it causes the replication issues?

Comment: I think I have a breakthrough... We used rocksdb engine.. When I switched back to memory mapped files the replication started to work flawlessly...
Does it make sense that rocksdb caused the replication issues?

Comment: There are definitely differences in the two storage engines (RocksDB and MMFiles). However, replication is supposed to work with both storage engines and not just one. So on the slave you are only reading data and with RocksDB it gets stuck? That sounds like a bug then!

Comment: It may be a side effect of a bug that is fixed in release 3.2.8, but that is pure speculation, as I haven't reproduced the problem yet.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it was a bug in ArangoDB 3.2.2
In ArangoDB 3.2.8 The replication seems to work (even with rocksdb).